# Selected just only one value option from several option

Tags: html, html-select

```
<pre>
<td>
    <select name="proses1" class="form-control">
    <option value="0" selected>-------</option>
    <option value="1">1-Itemset</option>
    <option value="2">2-Itemset</option>
    <option value="3">3-Itemset</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="proses2" class="form-control">
    <option value="0" selected>-------</option>
    <option value="1">1-Itemset</option>
    <option value="2">2-Itemset</option>
    <option value="3">3-Itemset</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="proses3" class="form-control">
    <option value="0" selected>-------</option>
    <option value="1">1-Itemset</option>
    <option value="2">2-Itemset</option>
    <option value="3">3-Itemset</option>
</select>
</td>
</pre>
```

i have tag html like above.. and i want for example i selected 1-itemset from proses1 and then i choose 1-itemset from proses2,
1-itemset from proses1 it get back to default(-------),
so the point is i want option just can selected one option.. how i can make it. thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you havent said what type of process you want, i suggest you do it with jquery like

```
var selects = $("select[name=proses1],select[name=proses2],select[name=proses3]");
selects.on("change",function(evt){
  selects.not("[name=" + evt.target.name + "]").val(0);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YpH6T/)

**EDIT**

To use this, first you need to add `jQuery` library to your code then place this inside `$(document).ready()` method. As a summary, place the code below **inside your head section**.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var selects = $("select[name=proses1],select[name=proses2],select[name=proses3]");
  selects.on("change",function(evt){
    selects.not("[name=" + evt.target.name + "]").val(0);
  });
});
</script>
```

What this does is to add an `onChange` event handler with `.on("change")` method to the `select` elements and in that handler all `select` elements values are being set to `0` which is the very first `option` except the current one.

Comment: $Batu Zet i don't understand about jquery, how i use it

Comment: @mary13 Do you know javascript?

Comment: i don't know, i'm still newbie

Comment: I must say mary well done. I am still not able to understand his question.. :O